# C++/CLI good coding practice, Indexed properties if-check or try..catch?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

A rather short and simple question.

Let's use this piece of code:

```
public ref class Foo
{
private:
    System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<System::String ^,System::String ^> ^ aDictionary;

public:

    property System::String ^ SomeIndexedProperty[System::String ^]
    {
    public: System::String ^ get(System::String ^ index)
            {
                return aDictionary[index];
            }
    }

public:
    Foo(void)
    {
        aDictionary = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<System::String ^,System::String ^>();
    }
};
```

Would it be better to surround/pre-check the return with an if statement ( `if( aDictionary->ContainsKey(index) )` or would it be better to surround the return statement with a try..catch block?

In both cases returning nullptr when they fail.

Speed is not really of the issue. But just a general "this is better for that reason" would suffice.

Comment: Returning nullptr is the wrong thing to do in the vast majority of cases.  Add an HasValue() method so that the client code can discover that the value isn't present.  If the usage dictates that the value should always be present then do nothing so that the client programmer can fix his bugs easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I firmly believe that if there is a legal condition that you reasonably allow, you should not catch an exception to detect it. In other words, use an `if` statement. This is akin to letting all loops on arrays run out until you get an `ArrayIndexOfBoundsException` and try...catch it into oblivion.

On a related note, it might make sense for the property to throw a `KeyNotFoundException` instead o returning `null`. Callers might take this `null` and try to dereference it, which shifts the focus and makes it harder to find the bug.

Comment: I concur, exceptions are for Exceptional circumstances, not routine failures.

Comment: +1. Let the exception propagate and let the clients catch the `KeyNotFoundException`. This is clearer and simpler for both you and the client.

Comment: Yeah, in tiny homework for your teacher, these are the right answers.
Leave the try..catch block, and rename your method as "TryGet()" to make purists satisfied ;)

Comment: @BertuPG: In tiny homework for your teacher this would probably not matter at all. On the other hand, in a production application, I prefer getting a KeyNotFoundException inside the property rather than getting a NullReferenceException elsewhere, and intermittently (e.g. if the return value from the property were accessed only conditionally).

Comment: So just letting the property throw the KeyNotFoundException instead of catching itself would be more conveniant. As the latter would add an other if statement somewhere to see if the returned value is a nullptr or not. Got it. I will wait till tomorrow to see if there will be any comments downrating this, else I'll accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Givent the circumstances described by you, I think it depends only on your preferences.
Anyway, when the failing condition is deterministic, and you can anticipate it, it's always a better solution not use the try..catch block, and leave it only for non-deterministinc and unpredictable errors.

All arguments against exceptions instead of "if" blocks, are only about performances (speed, memory, stack, ecc...) and are accademic. In real word, when you need a totally exception-free method, and don't care about reasons of null return values, just put your 5 lines try..catch block, and forget it! ;)